# PHP similar_text is WAY too slow

Tags: php

I am trying to build an 'analysis' feature for my translation software. A translator will be able to analyze a project which checks for similarities in a glossary.

On a project with 10,000 rows (each row contains a source text between 1-500 characters) with a glossary containing 25,000 terms, my current analysis algorithm takes a RIDICULOUS amount of time. I need to get this down to a couple of minutes maximum.

My algorithm looks something like this (I removed code that doesn't effect performance):

```
foreach($rows as $row){ //10,000 rows
  $source = $rows["source"];
  
  $matchPercent = $glossary->findMatch($source); //This line of code is extremely slow

  $matchPercents[$matchPercent]++;
}

//Now I have an array of all the matching percentages and how many rows fall into each percentage match


public function findMatch($source)
{
    $highestMatchPercent = 0;
    foreach ($this->terms as $term) { //25,000 terms
        $matchPercent = 0;
        similar_text(strtolower($source), strtolower($term), $matchPercent);
        $matchPercent = floor($matchPercent);

        if ($matchPercent > $highestMatchPercent) $highestMatchPercent = $matchPercent;
        if ($highestMatchPercent == 100) return $highestMatchPercent; //Added effeciency
    }
    return $highestMatchPercent;
}
```

How can I achieve similar results and speed this process up?

I've tried levenshtein, but it's max character limit is a problem.

Comment: you are checking against everything. Is there a way you can reduce the amount you are checking against? 10,000 rows will take much longer than 2,000. A `WHERE` clause in your data might be a good start.

Comment: You basically have a double loop

Comment: You check every row against all glossary terms, so it amounts to 250 milion similar_text calls for texts up to 500 characters (and this is O(N**3) complexity algorithm). Why do you need to compute the same data again and again? I mean once you do this for a ROW store the result somewhere and dont compute it again. The result will be the same for it anyway?

Comment: @Mech The problem is that every row needs to be checked. The analysis runs on the whole project and complies the data into a table.

Comment: @blahy Each row is a different source translation, so saving the result won't do much for me.

Comment: Lest say you have a row and you calculate your findMatch for it and you get 17 as a result. Next time you call your script you will also get 17 for this row (unless terms changed). So what I dont understand is why storing this value for a row wont do much?

Comment: @blahy Translators upload their own glossaries and have very different project rows. The chance of a repeating row source and glossary term is low. It may be a slight efficiency in same cases.

Comment: I suppose the greater question is what algorithm are you using? Not for this code, but for the code that relies on this code?